# Having trouble accessing web api data from USDA using http client

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am wanting to access an API and gather some data from it.
Here's the link: https://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api

When I am requesting the data, I get a 404 unauthorized error message. On the website it says that it could be because the parameters are incorrect, which I think is my issue.

apikey is the actual key for the api

'''

```
    public async Task getInfo()
    {

        string response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api/api_GET/?key=apikey" +
            "key&commodity_desc=CORN&year__GE=2012&state_alpha=VA&format=JSON");
   
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
```

'''

Comment: If you paste that **exact** URL into a web browser, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your issue here is the inclusion of `key` at the beginning of the second string.  Try the following:

```
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api/api_GET/?key=apikey" +
            "&commodity_desc=CORN&year__GE=2012&state_alpha=VA&format=JSON");
```

Answer (score 0):

This 404 error is showing up because you need to pass the "apikey" key in your url. Make the request on the website itself.

[image]